# Tabs Slide With Activity Pages

Tags: android, tabs, android-viewpager, android-tabhost, slide

I am trying to have 3 sliding tabs with activities.
The current example I have slides correctly but I can't seem to use my activities for the tab content.

MainActivity

```
package com.example.tabsslide;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.OnTabChangeListener;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnTabChangeListener, OnPageChangeListener{  
    private TabHost host;  
    private ViewPager pager;  
 @Override  
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  
   host = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);  
   pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);  

   host.setup();  
   TabSpec spec = host.newTabSpec("tab1");  
   spec.setContent(R.id.tab1);  
   spec.setIndicator("First tab");   
   host.addTab(spec);  

   spec = host.newTabSpec("tab2");  
   spec.setContent(R.id.tab2);  
   spec.setIndicator("Second tab");  
   host.addTab(spec);  

   spec = host.newTabSpec("tab3");  
   spec.setContent(R.id.tab3);  
   spec.setIndicator("Third tab");  
   host.addTab(spec);  

   pager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(this));  
   pager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);  
   host.setOnTabChangedListener(this);  
 }  
    @Override  
    public void onTabChanged(String tabId){  
         int pageNumber = 0;  
         if(tabId.equals("tab1")){  
              pageNumber = 0;  
         } else if(tabId.equals("tab2")){  
              pageNumber = 1;  
         } else{  
              pageNumber = 2;  
         }  
         pager.setCurrentItem(pageNumber);  
    }  
    @Override  
    public void onPageSelected(int pageNumber) {  
         host.setCurrentTab(pageNumber);  
    }
    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    }
```

MyPagerActivity

```
package com.example.tabsslide;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {  
    private Context ctx;  
    public MyPagerAdapter(Context ctx){  
         this.ctx = ctx;  
    }  
    @Override  
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {  
         TextView tView = new TextView(ctx);  
         position++;  
         tView.setText("Page number: " + position);  
         tView.setTextColor(Color.RED);  
         tView.setTextSize(20);  
         container.addView(tView);  
         return tView;  
    }  
    @Override  
    public int getCount() {  
         return 3;  
    }  
    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return (view == object);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(View container, int position, Object object) {
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((View) object);
    }
}
```

I have another example where the tabs navigate with clicks and show each activity screen.
The activity content is set on each tab using

```
           TabSpec tab1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("First Tab");
            tab1.setIndicator("Tab1");
            tab1.setContent(new Intent(this,Tab1Activity.class));
```

I want to be able to use the sliding tabs example to slide between activity screens.

Thanks in advance.